# spliting comma separated values and storing in separate row in python 3.x?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have the following python list:

```
original =    [(7782, 'Mandarin, Chinese'), 
(7783, 'Italian, Conversational Spanish'), 
(7792, 'Spanish, English'), 
(7793, 'English, Italian')]
```

What I want as result is like this:

```
[(7782, 'Mandarin'),
(7782, 'Chinese'),
(7783, 'Italian'),
(7783, 'Coversational Spanish'),
(7792, 'Spanish'),
(7792, 'English'),
(7793, 'English'),
(7793, 'Italian') ]
```

I am new to python. How can I achieve this? My code so far is like so:

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","123456","itutor" )
cursor = db.cursor()
query = "SELECT distinct user_id, language from table;"
cursor.execute(query)
r = list(cursor.fetchall())
db.close()
r2 = r[0][1].split(",")
```

Comment: Can you achieve your goal by accessing the database and changing the data there? I mean can you access a commandline interface and process a suitable SQL query?

Comment: The number of languages are not fixed. I can't use a query.

Comment: That does not sound like a reason not to do it via a query. A recursive CTE is likely able to achieve what you want. So, can you use commandline interface or not?

Comment: Yes I can. CTE are not available in MySQL 5.5. Also, its easier to do it with a programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can't resolve the issue upstream, you can use a nested list comprehension:

```
res = [(num, lang) for num, languages in original for lang in languages.split(', ')]

[(7782, 'Mandarin'),
 (7782, 'Chinese'),
 (7783, 'Italian'),
 (7783, 'Conversational Spanish'),
 (7792, 'Spanish'),
 (7792, 'English'),
 (7793, 'English'),
 (7793, 'Italian')]
```

To understand how this is constructed, consider the equivalent `for` loop:

```
res = []
for num, languages in original:
    for lang in languages.split(', '):
        res.append((num, lang))
```